# MysqlNonTransientException: client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading Mysql client

Tags: java, mysql, exception, transient

i have updated version of mysql 8.0.13 and i face a error during java programming that MysqlNonTransientException: client does not support authentication requested by server; consider upgrading Mysql client.what i do?

i don't know what to do..

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Example1
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection 
 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","manish@345");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select* from stu_info");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" 
"+rs.getInt(3));
            con.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  }
}
```

i want the program give a stu_info table details.

Comment: Your query `select* from stu_info` is missing a space after `select`.  It should be `select * from stu_info`.  Please fix this problem and then see if your current error persists.

Comment: sorry sir it's not working i tried @TimBiegeleisen